# How to store only time; not date and time?

Tags: sql, oracle, time

In one field I need to store not a datetime pair, i.e. a standard Oracle date.

```
01/10/2009 22:10:39
```

But time only

```
22:10:39
```

I think that save disk space (I have 2 million rows) or provide faster processing.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things, 2 million rows is practically nothing.  Is the meager space saving worth the loss in precision?

Comment: I guess the question I should have asked is "faster processing of what?"  If all you have it time-of-day, you can't compare it to anything else reliably, so you could just not store anything and save yourself the whole 7 bytes per row.

Comment: Another application area where time-of-day should only be stored but we don't care about a date: repeating event starting times. E.g. an event's start and end times are stored in MTG_START and MTG_END. But these apply to different days/dates, depending on the week. I want to only store the times of day so I don't confuse future developers/users of the database table. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could try the INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND data type but it won't save you any disk space ... it is very suitable for this purpose though.

```
create table t1 (time_of_day interval day (0) to second(0));

insert into t1 values (TO_DSINTERVAL('0 23:59:59'));

select date '2009-05-13'+time_of_day
from   t1;
```

11 bytes though.

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet would probably be storing "seconds since midnight" as a number field.

```
SELECT to_char( SYSDATE, 'SSSSS' ) FROM dual;
```

Comment: Of course, you must factor in (1) perofrmance penalty for always converting values and (2) developement time penalty for using weird calculations for otherwise standard date arithmetics.

Comment: @jva: yeah, I was going to mention that but by the time I thought of it I figured this thread was pretty much dead so why bother

Comment: I do like this approach but it's worth mentioning two things. The data should be stored in a number to ensure that you can't insert characters and there should be a check constraint on the column ensuring that you can't input more than 24 hours in seconds in.

Answer (score 3):

You can extract the time from a date as a string like this:

```
to_char(sysdate,'HH.MI.SS')
```

but there is no time-only data type that will help you save space.

Comment: If you store it as a VARCHAR anything can be stored in the column, which isn't very useful when trying to get it out again.

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
TO_CHAR(<DATE_COLUMN>, '<TIME_FORMAT>');
```

example

```
TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'HH24:MI:SS');
```

for time format you can check in [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_nls_date_format_sysdate.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You would save a few Mb of disk space(which is nothing nowadays) and you would gain next to nothing in performance.

You could use a column of `NUMBER` type for storing the number of seconds since midnight as suggested, just don't forget about the constraints.
(You'd probably use `NUMBER(5, 0)` which uses 1-3 bytes depending on the stored value, instead of a constant 7 bytes used by a `DATE` column)