# Insert TIME into Oracle SQL, DATE field

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Is there anyway to insert only time (no date) into a SQL field of type 'Date'

I have tried inserting:

```
13:00
```

and

```
01:00
```

and

```
13:00pm
```

and

```
01:00pm
```

But keep getting the error:

```
Not A Valid Month
```

Comment: How should it be done? No wait - WHY?

Comment: The clue is in the data-type name... it's a _date_... A date has a day, a month and a year...

Comment: I used "storing times in Oracle" in a search engine and found some articles on this.  You might try that.  I also found an interval data type in the Oracle documentation.  That might meet your needs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store in the field only time, not date + time pair?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786418/how-to-store-in-the-field-only-time-not-date-time-pair)

Comment: @Ben: In Oracle a `DATE` also includes a time part. You cannot insert **only** a time into a `DATE` column.

Comment: You can @a_horse_with_no_name, it'll just wind up with todays date. I'm not 100% certain which of my comments you're referring to. My first was trying to point out to the OP that they De missing the date part.of a date and the second is a dupe..?

Comment: @Ben: I was referring to "*A date has a day, a month and a year*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the literal.  For date/time values, Oracle expects values in the form ddMMMyyyy.  (Or, you can use the expression `DATE '2001-01-01`.  Literal values are explained [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ).)  There doesn't appear to be a default format for time without a date.

In other words, you can get the same error with `cast('1/1/2001' as date)`.

Instead, use the `to_date()` function:

```
select to_date('10:00', 'hh:mi')
from dual
```

This gives you much more flexibility with formats.

Also, as Ben notes in the comments, this gives you the current date with the time specified.

Comment: This will insert into the table the current date and so you always have to remember to remove it afterwards. It's better to store it in an INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND or the number of seconds since midnight as in the dupe.

Comment: @Ben . . . That is correct.  Thank you for further clarification.  I was only addressing why the error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

Example of using EXTRACT and time only portion of a SYSDATE and some date...:

```
SELECT hh||':'||mi||':'||ss time_only_portion
  FROM
  ( 
  Select
    EXTRACT(hour   From Cast(SYSDATE as timestamp)) hh,
    EXTRACT(minute From Cast(SYSDATE as timestamp)) mi,
    EXTRACT(second From Cast(SYSDATE as timestamp)) ss
  From dual
 )
/

SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR From t_stamp) hh
  FROM
 (
 SELECT CAST(to_date('21/02/2012 06:10:00 am', 'dd/mm/yyyy  hh:mi:ss am') AS TIMESTAMP) t_stamp 
   FROM dual
 )
/
```