# inserting current system time in table through a keyword using sql query

Tags: sql, oracle10g

just like **sysdate** inserts the current date,

Is there any way to insert **only** the **current time** using a sql query.

for example *insert into table_name values(sysdate); *

Comment: Why you'd want to do this, I don't quite understand. Normally, time without a date is meaningless. Furthermore, as there's no "time" data-type you can't store this in a date field, which is what your current insert statement implies. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786418/how-to-store-only-time-not-date-and-time and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045600/insert-time-into-oracle-sql-date-field

Answer (score 0):

There is no Oracle data type that represents just a hours/minutes/seconds. There is `DATE` and the various `TIMESTAMP` types that represents a point in time, including date and time. You don't say why you're trying to store this, but you could store the time as an offset in a NUMBER column, as fractions of a day.

So, if you wanted to find store the time of day that a store opens on Monday, you'd do:

```
TRUNC( SYSDATE ) + offset
```

Comment: Seconds since midnight or an interval datatype is more common as per the linked questions. 1/3 of a day could cause problems...

Comment: Why would seconds since midnight be better than fraction of a day? You wind up always having to do a conversion with your addition. (I agree it's less intuitive.) Intervals are also an option, though I've seen some weird things happen with execution plans and interval math.

Comment: actually i am designing a website for quiz so i want to show the time spent for the test. that's why i am trying to take difference of time.Is there any other way to do this? plz suggest.

Comment: In that case, I would store the time taken as a scalar, number of seconds or fraction of a day. You could also store the start and end of the test as a DATE and subtract the two to find the time taken.