# Oracle time data type

Tags: oracle, date, time, types

Is there anyway to have a variable of type time with this format '14:21'? Only with hours and minutes. I've seen lots of examples but all with seconds, milliseconds and that isn't useful at all for me in this context.

Comment: possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786418/how-to-store-only-time-not-date-and-time/).

Comment: you can always `TO_CHAR(yourdate, 'HH24:MI');`

Comment: You can use the `date` datatype and just ignore everything but the minutes and seconds. How you do so, though, depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope, not in Oracle. Check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG004).

You have datetime data types: DATE, TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, and TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE.

And you have interval data types: YEAR TO MONTH and DAY TO SECOND.

None of the above contains just hours and minutes.

Answer (score 0):

As there are always 24 hours in a day you can also use a NUMBER from 0 to 24*60=1440 representing the number of minutes and then convert this to time in the destination