# What format does Oracle expect for a `DATE` value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I used the relational model in SQL Model developer from Oracle to create this table:

```
  CREATE TABLE Orders
  (
    OrderNum                   INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    OrderDate                  DATE ,
    TIME                       DATE ,
    Employee_EMP_CODE          VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL ,
    Tax_Id                     VARCHAR2 (10) ,
    Tax_Rate                   VARCHAR2 (10) ,
    Customers_Customer_No      INTEGER NOT NULL ,
    Consoles_Console_NO        VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL ,
    Customers_Buyer_First_Name VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL ,
    Customers_Buyer_Last_Name  VARCHAR2 (10) NOT NULL ,
    Comments                   VARCHAR2 (250)
  ) ;
```

For some reason it will not take the time value when I try to insert a row.  I have tried these formats

- `'12:31:00'`
- `'12.31.00'`

It keeps giving me the error that the month value isn't valid.

Comment: What exactly are you putting in the `OrderDate` and/or `TIME` columns?  It looks like you meant `TIME` to be of type `TIME` not `DATE`

Comment: I had the relational modeler create the DDL for me, this is what it gave me.  Should I change the time column to TIME instead of date?

Comment: in your `TIME` column, are you trying to store only the time (and not any elements of a date)? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786418/how-to-store-only-time-not-date-and-time

Comment: It represents a time the order was placed so it is static

Comment: Not related to your question, but combining `customer` and `order` information in the same table violates normalization.  It would make much more sense to have separate `customer` and `orders` tables and to define the `CustomerNum` in `Orders` as a foreign key to the `customers` table.

Comment: Thanks I do have separate customers and orders table for some reason the DDL generator through this in and customersNo since i identified it as a many to one relatioship.  There is more to the DDL than I posted identifying the foreign keys sorry.  But thanks for the heads up

Comment: Combine both OrderDate and TIME in a single DATE column, everything else is just stupid.

Comment: Oracle does not support a "time only data type"

Answer (score 2):

An Oracle `date` column always has a day and a time component.  It makes no sense to have two columns `OrderDate` and `Time` both of type `date`.  Your `OrderDate` would have a time component and your `Time` would have a day component.  Realistically, you just want a single column of type `date` that has both the day and the time that the order was placed.

If you are trying to insert data into a `date` column, you would either want to pass the proper data type from your client application (i.e. bind a `date` in your client application when you create your `insert` statement) or you would want to do an explicit conversion from a string using the `to_date` function.  For example

```
INSERT INTO Orders( OrderNum, OrderDate, <<more columns>> )
  VALUES( 1, to_date( '2014-07-12 12:31:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' ), <<more values>> );
```

Comment: Thanks Justin this is for a homework assingment where we had to develop and ERD then Relational model.  We had to base it off of three invoices from motorcycle stores, but that's all we had to go with.  I think I will just change it to varchar2 and say the hell with it.  At this pint after being on these boards I don't think folks in the real world would do things the way he has taught us to do them.

Comment: @user3786519 - I would strongly advise you not to use a `varchar2` column to store a `date`.  Use an actual `date` column.

Comment: Right thanks. I have the month section in a date type, which for this assignment is the important part.  In all honesty he never even told us how to use date types so I'm not sure what he is expecting.

Comment: @user3786519 - That doesn't make sense.  As I said, a `date` always has a day and a time.  You can't have a "month section in a date type" without having everything else.  Now, you could say that you have a `date` where the day is always the 1st of the month and the time component is always midnight.  But then it would make no sense to store that additional data in another column.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question "*What format does Oracle expect for a DATE value?*"

You can look at your NLS_DATE_FORMAT:

> SQL> SHOW NLS_DATE_FORMAT

Assuming you're using Default, it should come back with something like: DD-MON-RR

You could actually insert or select without To_Date like this:
Select * from Orders Where OrderDate = '25-DEC-04';

To answer your real question: How should I store my orderDate :)

It seems you're storing Order Date, and Order Time in two separate fields.
There is really no need to do this, as this means you'll be using twice the disc space for your data field, which you only actually need 1 field.

as DATE datatype will store both Date and Time, you can actually just use 1 field, and this will make life a lot easier when trying to select your data as well.

You really should look at using sysdate at the moment your order is place.
ie:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR
    (SYSDATE, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') "OrderDate"
     FROM DUAL;

NOW
-------------------
04-13-2001 09:45:51
```

Also please notice that i've made use of TO_CHAR for printing purposes only.
when inserting, you will simply do:

> Insert into Orders(OrderDate, *other fields*) Values (sysdate, *other fields*);

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is very annoying when it comes to date stuff.  However, I have had good luck with this format:

```
{ts 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss'}
```

year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds.  Use leading zeros if appropriate.  Use 24 hour clock for hours.