# Looking To Create A Table With A Time Field

Tags: oracle, time, create-table

I am creating some tables from MS Access to Oracle and am having problems with the time field.

The table below entertainers is expecting timestamp to be in the format of YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS etc.

I am looking to declare it as Time only field to hold values such as 22:00:00.

Is this possible?

```
CREATE TABLE Engagements (
EngagementNumber number NOT NULL ,
StartDate date NULL ,
EndDate date NULL ,
StartTime timestamp NULL ,
StopTime timestamp NULL ,
ContractPrice decimal(15,2) NULL ,
CustomerID int NULL ,
AgentID int NULL ,
EntertainerID int NULL 
);
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be more conventional to combine the date and time components into single columns of start_datetime and end_datetime. Separating them offers no advantages, and there is no TIME data type.

EDIT: Just in response to comments, I of course agree that a TIME data type would have its uses, but in this answer I'm speaking only in the context of whether a DATETIME should be split into separate DATE and TIME elements (which it should not).

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for that. There are instances where I would prefer to have just a time field.

For example:



CREATE TABLE Classes (
 ClassID number NOT NULL ,
 SubjectID number NULL ,
 ClassRoomID number NULL ,
 Credits number NULL,
 StartTime time NULL
)

Comment: @ribena1980 - if you aren't specifying the date (though you are in your question), [David has answered that secnario before too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1786418/266304). There isn't a separate time-only [data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF0021) you can use for a table column.

Comment: Not speaking for the OP (his problem is probably different), but there IS a scenario where it would make sense to have a "time-of-day" data type. Suppose I have a table with dates (date data type, meaning date and time-of-day) and I want to select only those that are during business hours, between 9 am and 5 pm. In Oracle we have to jump through hoops to store "9 am" and "5 pm" as data bits - there is no "natural" way to do that. It is what it is, but the idea that "you should never need pure time-of-day data type, if you think you do you are probably doing something wrong" is excessive IMO.