# How to insert only hour and minute into table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tried this:

```
INSERT INTO Airplanes 
VALUES (1, 'Boeing 720-020', 'New York', TO_DATE('17:30', 'HH24:MI'), 219);
```

But after running it, in the table I have `10/01/2018` instead of `17:30`.

I'm really grateful for your help.

Comment: There is no such "time" data type in oracle.  DATE type contains month,day,year.  Maybe if you could explain better what it is you are trying to accomplish, we can think further.   See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786418/how-to-store-only-time-not-date-and-time) also for a suggested solution.

Comment: Ty, I want a hour:minute record in my table

Comment: @Noktua - but what will you do with the data once you have it? You could just store a string literal `'17:30'` in a `varchar2` column, but someone could put garbage in. You could store it as you are and ignore the date part. You don't quite have 10/01/2018 in your table, that's just how your client is displaying it - change your NLS_DATE_FORMAT or use `to_char()` to display the stored time too (or instead). It will actually have stored 17:30:00 on the first day of the current month, since you didn't specify the date parts.

Comment: Store the value as an integer number of minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DATE in Oracle is actually a datetime datatype. There is no TIME datatype. So if you want to store a time only then you need to use a string.

```
create table airplane (
  id number primary key
  , plane_type varchar2(32) not null
  , destination  varchar2(32) not null
  , flight_time varchar2(5) not null check (regexp_like(flight_time, '[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}'))
)
/
```

The check constraint enforces a format of `99:99`. You can make if stricter if you wish.

---

I have some sympathy with @AlexPoole that we should use a DATE column to store a time, because it does make it easier to ensure that only valid times are entered. But then we have to restrict the date part to make sure it is always the same magic date and we always have to apply a format mask whenever we query the table to make sure it only displays the time. So we gain something but we also lose something.

There are more baroque solutions. You could define flight_time as an interval:

```
 , flight_time interval day to second
```

Then your insert statement would be

```
insert into airplane 
values (1, 'Boeing 720-020','New York',INTERVAL '0 17:30:0' DAY TO SECOND);
```

You'd still want a check that the DAY element was zero. And I think the queried output would still need formatting.

But I suspect we're starting to over-engineer what appears to be a course assignment. So stick with the string unless you need something better,

Answer (score 2):

You can try using to_char function.

Example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'HH24:MI') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: The OP does not want the time element of the current date. They want to be able to **store** a time without a date element

Answer (score 0):

You can store time as what you've shown:

```
TO_DATE('17:30', 'HH24:MI')
```

Your table `Airplanes` has a column of `date` data type (which is actually date and time as [stated by APC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52841004/5399719)) where you tried to store that time. Your time is indeed stored but it comes with a date that you did not specify and defaulted to the first day of the current month.

Your only problem is that Oracle showed you the date when you `select`ed it. So, to get over with that, just use `to_char()` to only display the time in a particular format, like so:

```
select to_char(column_name,'HH24:MI') from Airplanes;
```

If you'd go down this road, let me suggest to store also the date of that time so you won't end up with useless dates in your records. So if, for example, you're storing the flight time, also store the date of the flight on that same column, like so:

```
TO_DATE('2018-10-17 17:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
```

Also, use the `date` data type so that you can take advantage of the built-in date/time functions like easily displaying the time in a particular format.